# Spring MVC - Jackson deserialize braces

Tags: spring, jackson

I have REST POST method which accepts @RequestBody String name.
When I send there from Postman json like this:

```
{
 "name": "some_name"
 }
```

I get a String variable which contains: '{ "name": "some_name" }'.

But when I send from postman just some_name I get variable which contains 'some_name'.
How it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are telling Jackson to parse the payload into a String, so it does. If you want Jackson to parse a JSON payload into a POJO, do something like:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping("my/endpoint")
    public NameDto post(@RequestBody NameDto dto) {
        // do stuff
        return dto;
    }

    class NameDto {
        private String name;

            public NameDto() { }

            public String getName() {
                return this.name;
            }
            publid void setName(String s) {
                this.name = s;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your use case, you may want to refactor `NameDto` into it's own file and modify the access to public.